# 図形のUIViewのアニメーション

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c, swift2

円形のビューを作って、枠線の色を赤から青、青から赤と延々と繰り返すようにしたいのです。
以下の方法だと、赤から青にはなりますが、その状態から止まりリピートされません。
オプションに[UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse , UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat]を入れてるので問題ないと思ったのですが。
何か足らない部分は有るでしょうか。

```
    //この時点で円形にします
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width/2;
    button.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    //枠線
    button.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
    //枠線の色
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 1, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse , UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat], animations: { () -> Void in
        self.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

コードをコピーして改造して試してみましたが、self.button.layer.borderColorの色はアニメーションで変化していませんでした。
ビューの移動アニメーションと背景色変更アニメーションを追加して動かしてみたところ、ちゃんとリピート再生はされるようです。
参考までに改造したコードを載せておきます。

```
    //この時点で円形にします
    self.button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width/2;
    self.button.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    //枠線
    self.button.layer.borderWidth = 5.0;
    //枠線の色
    self.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor

    //初期位置の指定
    button.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y:200)
    //背景色の指定
    self.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 1, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse , UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat], animations:{() -> Void in
        self.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        //移動アニメーション
        self.button.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y:500)
        //背景色アニメーション
        self.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    }, completion:{_ in
        //self.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    })
```

下記URLでも、CaLayerのborderColorはUIAnimationでアニメーションさせることはできないとあります。
http://qiita.com/ShingoFukuyama/items/66d2ca049e15bd340538

そもそもアニメーションせずに、ボーダーが最初から青いままなのだと思いますがどうでしょうか？
上記URLに別解があるようですので、そちらを参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

XCodeのバージョンは7.3.1(7D1014)、動作環境はiPad4th、iOS9.3.2(13F69)で検証しました。